# GotoMyPC ? Concerns or OK?

Tags: security, remote-access, evaluation

A few users have taken it upon themselves to install this software on there work computers and use iphones/ipads to connect. Current setup is anyconnect / ciscovpn to connect and use remote desktop to work from home. The cisco web portal also has access to a few intranet related systems.

The network is behind a Cisco ASA and contains only company PCs & servers. all other devices use a guest network which is segregated from the main.

Is anyone familiar with allowing GotoMyPC in this kind of situation? Is there precautions I should take, should I not allow it, or is it fine?

My main concern is by using this piece of software, I am bypassing our firewall systems and opening up doors that I don't want to open.

Looking for some feedback from someone in a similar situation due to me being unfamiliar with the service.

Thanks.

Comment: Your user are allowed to install software?

Comment: @jscott The vp/presidents/managers (take laptops home) are.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This seems like a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've got an approved remote desktop solution in place (which you do) I would have your users use that.  There are RDP applications available for the iPad (I use one regularly to connect to my PC from my iPad) and there is VPN software available for the iPad.

Personally I would block the use of GoToMyPC as it isn't the approved way into the network and it opens your network up to an unmonitored way onto the network.

You'll of course need to work with the iPad users to get them to understand how to VPN in via their iPads before shutting them down.  This is probably a good way to get the company to buy you one for research use.

Comment: thanks, we have an ipad for research use. I am unfamiliar with i products but this is basically the decision that first came to mind when this was brought to my attention.